# Is there anyway to verify a function call was made by the document and not a user

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I am making an app that uses a money system where the money is stored in local storage. I have used a process to obfuscate the money while in local storage and only convert it to easily readable data when necessary. (I am aware that data stored on a users computer is  never completely secure, the money system can't affect any other users so it's fine though.) Here is the process I use to add 100 dollars to their account:

```
getMoney(); //gets money from obfuscated local storage and converts it into readable data
money += 100;
saveMoney(); //obfuscates money and stores in local storage.
```

I am not worried about people editing the local storage, but someone could easily run:

```
money = 100000;
saveMoney();
```

I am asking if there is anyway to insure that the function call was made by the document and not the user. I have looked on stack exchange and other websites but I can't seem to figure out a reliable way. 
 (Perhaps requiring an obfuscated key in the function parameters?)

Comment: No, there's no way to do this. And even if you could, it wouldn't help. The user could simply set a breakpoint in the debugger, change the value of `money`, and continue the script.

Comment: Using an IIFE will help a tiny bit, and obfuscation of your Javascript code will help some, but there's no *reliable* way. The client can do anything and execute anything they want. If you want to be sure, store and validate on the server, rather than the client.

Comment: You could make it harder by obfuscating the whole script, as that will make it harder for them to find the variable to change.